# render component passed through @ContentChildren or @ContentChild

Tags: angular

I'm doing content projection with @ContentChildren.

Now I have the need to put the components from the contentchildren query somewhere where I choose it to be. I also have to add an extra divider if not the last one in the array. So the reason is that based on a given list of components (content children) I need to create a new list with extra components in between...

How can this be done in Angular? I looked up for dynamic component injection but it's always starting from a component type being used to render a component. But in this case I already have the components in the ContentChildren query array...

Comment: Do you know the type of components projected? I mean, are you trying to implement a component like tabs which include child tab components?

Comment: I think there is more information needed to help you out. For what reason do you need to reposition the components? If they are in ContentChildren, I assume they are already defined somewhere in the template. Are the components all going to the same place? Best option would be to provide some code to get an idea...

Comment: I know the type yes and I even already have the components in the ContentChildren array (query)... I can loop through those components and print out properties. I just need to render it somewhere in the view like I want...

Comment: The reason is that based on a given list I need to create a new list with extra components in between...

Comment: I think you should read about `ng-template` and the use of its `createEmbeddedView()` method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is working [solution](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dnxwck)

To simulate what you want to implement, I've implemented two components, `tabs` and `tab`

You can use these components as follows

```html
<my-tabs>
  <my-tab text="Tab 1"></my-tab>
  <my-tab text="Tab 2"></my-tab>
  <my-tab text="Tab 3"></my-tab>
</my-tabs>

<div>------------------</div>

<my-tab text="This is rendered itself" [single]="true"></my-tab>
```

Within `TabComponent`, I've wrapped `ng-content` with `ng-template` so that I can inject it within component with `@ViewChild(TemplateRef) content`.

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'my-tab',
  template: `
    <ng-template>
      {{text}}
    </ng-template>

    <ng-container *ngIf="single">
      <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="content"></ng-container>
    </ng-container>
  `
})
export class TabComponent {
  @ViewChild(TemplateRef) content;

  @Input() text;
  @Input() single = false; // this will allow to use this component on its own
}
```

`TabsComponent`

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'my-tabs',
  template: `
    <div *ngFor="let tab of tabs; let isLast = last">
      <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="tab.content"></ng-container>
      <hr *ngIf="!isLast">
    </div>
  `,
})
export class TabsComponent  {
  @ContentChildren(TabComponent) tabs: QueryList<TabComponent>;
}
```

You can use `tab.content` within `*ngTemplateOutlet` directive.

`<ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="tab.content"></ng-container>`

Comment: In my example the TabComponent is a RemarkComponent and already has a specific html. So the html of the child component is already defined and is not generic.

Comment: You can still wrap it with `ng-template` and let `TabsComponent` do the rendering.

Comment: you're the savior!

Comment: @stephan.peters thank you, I'm glad it solved your problem :)

Comment: Still a problem: I wrapped the RemarkComponent (TabComponent) in the ng-template. But now it doesn't want to show if I use it outside the list.

Comment: @stephan.peters I've updated the stackblitz and the answer

Comment: I get this error in dev modus which I'm trying to solve: Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'ngTemplateOutlet: undefined'. Current value: 'ngTemplateOutlet: [object Object]  Do you know how to solve this?